# ensuring objects go into the right bucket

Tags: javascript, constraint-programming

I have these unique, distinct items.

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Buckets currently show the possibilities of where each item can go. Items can only go where they are allowed.

```
possiblebuckets = [
  [1, 6, 3, 4], [7, 3, 6], [5, 3, 1], [3, 2, 4], [2], [2], [2, 3]
]
```

I want each bucket to have 1 item. I want to make sure that I can put items into a bucket such that maximum number of items are put into a bucket. It's ok if some items can't fit into a bucket or if some buckets remain empty.

Result should be:

```
finalbuckets = [
  [6], [7], [1], [4], [2], [], [3]
]
```

For example a naive way of doing it:

```
      items.forEach(function (item) {
        var findMatch = possiblebuckets.filter(function (bucket, i) {
          return bucket.includes(item)
        });

        findMatch.length = 0
        findMatch.push(item);
      });
```

Results in items not being put into the optimal bucket.

Comment: requires some further explanations I guess, also an input/output example would help.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance consider using services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: If they're "unique", how come your example has duplicate values...?

Comment: @YannickK in the items array they are unique, the buckets only show where they are allowed to go, there should be only 1 in the end.

Comment: Sounds very much like a [MAX-CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), but i can't quite pin down which one

Comment: `1, 6, 5, 4, 2, _, 3`, `1, 7, 5, 4, 2, _, 3`, `6, 7, 1, 4, 2, _, 3`, `6, 7, 5, 4, 2, _, 3` are all valid solutions. Why is `6, 7, 1,...` the correct one?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you're right, so long as as many are used as possible they are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty here's my solution:

```js
      var oneLevelDeepClone = function (obj) {
        return obj.map(function (bucket) {
          return bucket.map(function (item) {
            return item
          })
        })
      }

      var maxDeployments;
      var maxDeploymentsCount = 0;

      function constraintProblem (tempBuckets) {
        const tryAgain = [];

        var iterativeTempBuckets = oneLevelDeepClone(tempBuckets)
        var innerTempBuckets = oneLevelDeepClone(iterativeTempBuckets)
        innerTempBuckets.forEach(function (bucket, bucketIndex) {
          var keep = bucket.shift();
          if (bucket.length) {
            // worth a try
            bucket.forEach(function (item) {
              var newAttempt = oneLevelDeepClone(innerTempBuckets)
              newAttempt[bucketIndex] = [item]
              tryAgain.push(newAttempt);
            })
          }

          if (keep) {
            // keep 1 and toss the others, then remove that one from the other buckets
            innerTempBuckets[bucketIndex] = [keep]
            innerTempBuckets.forEach(function (iterativeBucket, iterativeBucketIndex) {
              if (bucketIndex != iterativeBucketIndex) {
                if (iterativeBucket.indexOf(keep) != -1) {
                  iterativeBucket.splice(iterativeBucket.indexOf(keep), 1)
                }
              }
            })
          }
        })

        var counter = 0;
        innerTempBuckets.forEach(function (bucket) {
          if (bucket[0]) counter++
        })
        if (counter > maxDeploymentsCount) {
          maxDeploymentsCount = counter;
          maxDeployments = innerTempBuckets;
        }

        if (tryAgain.length) {
          tryAgain.forEach(function (anotherTry) {
            constraintProblem(anotherTry);
          })
        }
      }

possiblebuckets = [
  [1, 6, 3, 4], [7, 3, 6], [5, 3, 1], [3, 2, 4], [2], [2], [2, 3]
]
      constraintProblem(possiblebuckets)

console.log(maxDeployments);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>

<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: Here's [my approach](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/fybxh9L6/10/) explained.